# How to print out a slash (/ or \) in C?

Tags: c, printf

I know this is a very silly and simple question but I've been trying to print out an image of a robot that should output this:

```
+----------+
|          |
| /\    /\ |
| \/    \/ |
|          |
|  [-=-=-] |
+----------+
```

The part I'm stuck on is printing out the eyes.
originally I coded:

```
printf("| /\  /\ |");
printf("| \/  \/ |");
```

but an error showed, so I remembered that you need to double slash so:

```
printf("| \/\\  \/\\ |");
printf("| \\\/  \\\/ |");
```

but an error saying implicit declaration of function printf is showing even after that?! I don't understand the error. Can someone explain how to fix this please?

Comment: did you include `stdio.h`?

Comment: You need to put '\\'  for the back slash.

Comment: [Have you tried searching for an answer](https://www.google.fr/search?q=implicit+declaration+of+function+printf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=dIk3VabNK4PVPLDegfgM) before asking?

Comment: yes I have but it was not clear and abit confusing seeing that I have many slashes... most examples were only printing out one, this was a tricky example

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to escape forward slash.

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("| /\\  /\\ |");
  printf("| \\/  \\/ |");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use \ before backslash. Its separate the character.Like this

```
printf("| /\\  /\\ |\n");   
printf("| \\/  \\/ |");
```